# Différence entre « certain âge » et « âge certain »

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Je sais que *certain* fait partie des adjectifs qui peuvent tantôt suivre le nom, tantôt le précèdent (sens indéfini et défini respectivement). Je sais également que *certain* est plus précisément un déterminant. Par exemple :

> Un certain geste pourrait le toucher.
>
> Vider une région de ses jeunes,
> c'est l'assurer d'une mort certaine, à moyen ou à court terme.

Cependant je me demande quelle est la logique qui dicte que

> Marie est une femme d'un certain âge ; Jeanne est une femme d'un âge
> certain

signifie que Jeanne est plus âgée que Marie. Est-ce l'usage seulement ?

Comment: L'absence d'article dans *certain geste pourrait le toucher* est exceptionnelle et peut-être unique dans la littérature (*Topaze*, Marcel Pagnol). On s'attendrait soit à ***un** certain geste pourrait le toucher* (sens de la phrase dans Topaze) soit au pluriel : *Certains gestes pourraient le toucher*.

Comment: C'est super ! Bravo. Oui la citation est de Pagnol. Je ne trouvais pas la phrase exceptionnelle et donc je n'ai pas donné l'auteur. Je vais rajouter la citation.

Comment: Cette citation n'a que peu de rapport avec le reste. *Geste certain pourrait le toucher* n'a pas vraiment de sens.

Comment: D'accord:-)! Je vais la modifier.

Comment: Je viens de rajouter **un**. Est-ce mieux comme ça ? Ou est-il mieux que je l'efface ?

Comment: C'est bien comme ça. La phrase ne surprend plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'adjectif *certain* change de sens suivant qu'il est placé avant ou après un nom.

Le TLFi dispose d'ailleurs de deux entrées différentes.

Dans [le premier cas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/certain), il signifie *qui a un caractère particulier*. Dans le cas de la question, il s'agit d'un âge indéterminé mais significatif.

Dans [le deuxième cas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/certain/1), il indique une certitude. Dans le cas de l'âge, on est donc certains de l'âge avancé de la personne en question.

Cette différence n'est donc pas limitée à l'âge. On pourrait reprendre l'exemple d'utilisation « une mort certaine » et le comparer à « une certaine mort ».

Dans le premier cas, l'issue fatale ne fait pas de doute alors que dans la deuxième, l'expression se réfère à une façon de mourir mais sans préciser spécifiquement laquelle.

On retrouve les mêmes différences entre :

- un certain nombre - un nombre certain
- un certain temps - un temps certain
- un certain échec - un échec certain
- un certain avantage - un avantage certain
- une certaine valeur - une valeur certaine
  etc.

Answer (score 3):

Good question here.

I'm not aware of this difference having any precise linguistical root, but i believe it's more of a custom than anything else. As a french it always felt right to me that "certain age" meant a woman in her late 40s or 50s and that "age certain" was the next step, late 50s - 60s.
Sorry if i'm not being useful :S

Je ne connais pas de racine linguistique à cette différence et je pense que cela relève surtout de l'usage de la langue. Cela me paraît naturel d'avoir cet échelonnage de qualificatif, avec certain âge qui représnete la quarantaine-cinquantaine, et âge certain la cinquantaine-soixantaine.
Désolé de ne pas être plus utile :S